# Small change in field display using tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a simple tastypie resource:

```
class EntryResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = POI.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'poi'
```

This resource contains a field `geom`, which is a geometryfield. Tastypie outputs it as WKT (string). I would like to output it as geoJSON.

Is there a simple way to make EntryResource output attr.json instead of attr?

Answer (score 0):

In tastypie you can access field attributes when defining a resource field with [attribute](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#ApiField.attribute) e.g. to get a year from a date you can do

```
class EntryResource(ModelResource):
    year = fields.IntegerField(attribute='modified__year')
    ...
```

so you could try

```
attr_json = fields.CharField(attribute='attr__json')
```